# Replacing anonymous methods with expression tree

Tags: c#, anonymous-methods, expressionbuilder

If I want to replace this anonymous method:

```
Func<int, int> f = delegate(int i)
{
     return i + 1;
};
```

with an expression tree, it would like this:

```
ParameterExpression i = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "i");
Expression one = Expression.Constant(1, typeof(int));
Expression body = Expression.Add(i, one);
Func<int, int> f = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>>(body, i).Compile();
```

(I know: an expression tree will secretly dynamically create another anymous method, but that is not the point).

Now I want to replace the following method with an expression tree:

```
Func<int, int> f = delegate(int i)
{
     Debug.WriteLine("Inside the function!");
     return i + 1;
};
```

Is there a way and how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do the replacement. The structure of your current expression looks like this:

```
Expression.Lambda
    Expression.Add
        Expression.Parameter("a")
        Expression.Constant(1)
```

the structure of the new expression will look like this:

```
Expression.Lambda
    Expression.BlockExpression
        Expression.Call
            Expression.Constant("Inside the function!")
            MedhodInfo(Debug.WriteLine)
        Expression.Add
            Expression.Parameter("a")
            Expression.Constant(1)
```

You will need to provide `MedhodInfo` for the `Debug.WriteLine` to the `Call` expression. The last expression in the block (i.e. `a+1`) will be considered block's return expression.